# Core data many-to-many inverse relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have Addresses and AddressGroups, 
both addressed can be in many address groups and address groups can contain many addresses.

But I have a lot of them (more than 50 000 entities), and I want to skip using inverse relationship on addresses to spare some memory and CPU while creating them.

I did remove them, but I don't know if it will be consistent in Core Data due to warning

:`-1: AddressGroup.addresses does not have an inverse; this is an advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a specific relationship) [7]`

I wonder if that's possible without data leaks inside the database.

[Current scheme without an inverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Orqh.png)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the inverse causes memory or processor issues?

Comment: @Paulw11 It seems like that.
With an inverse it takes 8m 40s to run the algorithm and 10MB more in memory, while without it - it takes only 7m 15s and 10MB less in memory.